# Make app act as a Server

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoahttpserver

I'm using `CocoaHTTPServer`, and I'm able to start the server. In my resources folder, I added a file called "index.html", and here is something that made me confused.

- I can get the path of the index file by

  [mainbundle
     pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]

  but it gave me the path as
  `/Users/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/`.
  Is there any way to make the path become a web-url like
  `http://127.0.0.1:56000/user/library/.../index.html"` to load it on an
  UIWebView.
- I want to get the file path like the format above because I want to
  catch when the UIWebView request to it and when will the app
  response.

Is there any way for me to achieve it??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can load a resource into a `UIWebView` like this

   ```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"www"]];
   [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
   ```
2. For catching the requests of a `UIWebView` please check `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). You can play around with following method for example `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`

Comment: Hi @deimus
It's my bad, I was supposed to put the second question to the first. I want to make my app to act as a web server, and when a UIWebView want to load a html file in my phone, I can catch the request to it, and write a custom response. And that's why I want to load the file path as a web link, like "http://127.0.0.1:56000/index.html"

Comment: @JozoL please make it more clear what exactly you want to catch and when ?

Comment: And let me know if your still have questions

Comment: Hi @deimus
Thanks for your answers, but how about I want the app to act as a web server. When an UIWebView want to load the index.html file. The app know it, and write some thing to response before the UIWebView display the response content??

Comment: And for the first question, your solution doesn't include a port to the file url. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: very simple, just listen to `UIWebView` requests with `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` check the `url` its requests, decide what you want to load into your web view and load it

Comment: Don't stuck with `url` format, you can request with whatever format you want, then by catching the request, you can in fact load whatever content you want.

Comment: I think I should be clearer at the beginning. I've seen an project in Android, they create an Socket to listen to any request on the app (the app act as a web server - I think) and when the web view load the index.html file. The socket catch it, write some response and put it in the output stream of the socket, and send it back to the web view. I think it means that what the web view loaded is the content in the output sent by the socket, not the content of the index.html file.
That's all I want to achieve in iOs

Comment: @JozoL are you running the webview on the same device ? If yes then you don't need stuff like lightweight http server, as the manipulation with `UIWebView` is enough. If you are going to make requests from outside world, which I'm not currently 100% sure its possible as Apple has quite strict rules related to secure access etc. But still I'll check at the end of the day if it is possible to catch requests on `CocoaHttpServer` side, I'm sure it will be possible to do :). But you have to wait until I finish my workday, sorry

Comment: Hi @deimus
I run the UIWebView on the same device, in the app itself. Thanks for your help, but I think I'll need to dig around more. Someday if I had a chance, I'll buy you a beer.